# About : $I=\int_{a}^{b} f(x).g(x).dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

$f$ and $g$ are two continuous functions in $[a,b]$.

Suppose that $g$ has a constant sign (For example $g>0$).

Let $I=\int_{a}^{b} f(x).g(x).dx$

Does it exist $c\in]a,b[$ so that $I=f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x).dx$ ?

Comment: Perhaps the conclusion should be $I=f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x).dx$

Comment: Yes. I will change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=-1,b=1$, $f(x)=x, g(x)=x+2$. Then $g(x) >0$ and $\int_a^{b} f(x) \, dx=0, I=\frac 2 3$. So there is no such point $c$.

Comment: right! I guess c verifies : $I=f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x).dx$

Answer (score 0):

For the modified question the answer is yes.

Let m and M be the minimum and maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ and assume, without loss of generality, that $g(x)\gt 0$. Then $m\int_{a}^{b} g(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^{b} m\,g(x)\,dx\le \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)\,dx\le\int_{a}^{b} M\,g(x)\,dx=M\int_{a}^{b} g(x)\,dx$, so
$$m\le{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)\,dx\over {\int_{a}^{b} g(x)\,dx}}\le M$$ and because of the continuity of $f$ there is a $c\in[a,b]$ for which $f(c)$ equals the quotient. If the quotient equals $m$ or $M$ then $f$ must be constant and any $c$ in $(a,b)$ will do. If $f$ is not constant then $c$ can be found in the open interval between a point where $f$ is minimal and a point where $f$ is maximal.